# Allowing two subclass instances to access to each other's methods

Tags: c#, oop

I have 3 classes like this:

```
class MainClass
{
   public Status status1;
   public Control control1;
}

class Status
{
   MainClass mainClass;
   public void testStatus()
   {
      mainClass.control1.testControl();
   }
}

class Control
{
   public void testControl()
   {
   }
}
```

I don't know if the line "mainClass.control1.testControl()" is a correct job or a dirty one in OOP world. What's the solution for such a situation if it's not a good one.

Comment: If nothing else, `mainClass.control1.foo()` violates the [law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it doesn't really make sense. `MainClass` has a reference to both `Control`/`Status` therefore it seems the most logical controller object. However, you give no clear indication as to how each of these classes relate to eachother so there isn't much to go on there...

If `Status` is *depedant* on `Control` then control should be passed in explicitly i.e.

```
public class Status
{
    private Control control;

    public Status(Control control)
    {
        this.control = control;
    }

    public void testStatus()
    {
        this.control.TestControl();
    }
}
```

Also, assuming the `MainClass` reference in `Status` should be it's *parent* you would need to pass that in as well. However, if it's sole purpose is to invoke `TestControl` then it's not needed at all here.

Comment: This I like, I would only go a step further and make the constructor swallow an Interface. A bit like dependency injection.

Comment: @Silvermind yeah that's what I am getting at (DI) with my latest edit - although you don't necessarily need interfaces for that.

Comment: @James Thanks for your response. just a question: What if there's interconnection between two Control and Status classes? I mean calling Status functions from Control and vise versa.

Comment: You would update `Control` to have a reference to `Status` in that case - this is a form of [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) where both objects have a reference to eachother but they don't *own* eachother. Alternatively, to avoid this "cyclic" relationship you could result to using events and have the objects handle those instead so there is no dependencies at all. This all depends on your model though...

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how much you want to restrict access to sibling controls.

Perhaps have a method that takes the index of the control you want to test?

```
bool TestControl(int index)
{
    return controls[0].TestControl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example code, posted in the question, doesn't really follow the OO principles of 'high cohesion and low coupling'. Try to re-think the solution in such a way that `Status` does not need knowledge about `Control`. Consider looking at design patterns (like the 'Observer' pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Yes i find some problems,

1. There is cyclic dependency b/w Main and Status.
2. Responsibility is not handled properly

Your Main class holds the association with both Status and Control. From the code my understanding is that Status is a class that check on any give Control, but not associated with any particular control, So there is a weak association there..

In this situation i find passing the Control to the Status would be better.. 
Status testStatus method gets a argument of the Control to be tested and check returning back the status. 
Below is the code

**#1**

```
class MainClass
{
    public Status status1;
    public Control control1;
}

class Status
{        
    public void testStatus(Control control)
    {
        control.testControl();
    }
}

class Control
{
    public void testControl()
    {
    }
}
```

If more tight coupling is required, you can add Status as a property to Control. This way Main is only associated with Control which gives back Status when required. Responsibilities are properly sorted out.

**#2**

```
class MainClass
{
    Control control1;

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        control1 = new Control();
        Status control1Status = control1.GetStatus();
    }

}

class Status
{
    public Status(Control control)
    {
        //do status Initiation
        IsValid = true //or false
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

class Control
{
    public Status GetStatus()
    {
        return new Status(this);
    }
}
```

**#2** is better

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much info here, but you are right to suspect it's not nice code that you have. The reason being coupling. You are making your classes heavily dependent on each other and cross-referencing between them, which is bad.

I'd suggest using interfaces to solve this, something along the lines of:

```
public interface IStatus
{
    void TestStatus();
}

public interface Control
{
    void testControl();
}

public interface IMainClass {}

internal class MainClass : IMainClass
{
    public IStatus status1;
    public IControl control1;
}

internal class Status : IStatus
{
    public IMainClass mainClass;

    public void testStatus()
    {
        mainClass.control1.testControl();
    }
}

internal class Control : IControl
{
    public void testControl()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't really see what benefits using interfaces bring here? There are no other classes therefore the abstraction you get is nullable, ok it's future-proofing but it doesn't really address the main problem.

Comment: @James, what are the main problems? There is too little info in the OP to work out for sure any problems beyond the tight coupling, I would have thought.

Comment: Well there is a violation which is immediately obvious (`mainClass.control1.testControl` - [law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)). That highlights a general relationship problem between the objects, all interfaces do is abstract the implementation away, they don't actually resolve that problem.

Comment: @James, the interfaces remove the coupling between MainClass and Status, thus fixing the the violation of the law of Demeter. That was the whole point of suggesting the use of interfaces, to resolve the tight, bi-directional, coupling between the two classes.

Comment: @James, however, the discussion is pretty moot at this point. The OP has accepted your solution (which just moves the tight coupling from MainClass and Status to Controller and Status, thus achieving very little). Clearly doing it "properly" with interfaces was a step too far for the OP. <shrug/>

Comment: the law of demeter states that "*object A can request a service (call a method) of an object instance B, but object A cannot "reach through" object B to access yet another object, C, to request its services*" - your example here does *not* fix that violation because `Status` still calls `testControl` on `Control` via `MainClass`. My example follows a more DI approach whereby dependencies are injected into the relevant classes, the tight coupling only becomes an issue when there is the notion of different implementations, this is not even remotely suggested by the user...

Comment: So doing it "*properly*" does not mean using interfaces, it means fixing the relationship problem first and foremost. Making the solution more *flexible* would mean using interfaces.

Comment: @James, I disagree, Solving the "two dot" problem should come after solving the class coupling problem. Clearly we aren't going to agree on this though. Silvermind even pointed out to you that your answer would be better if you'd used interfaces, but you declined to do so. So on to the next question...

Comment: I declined to do so with good reason, the use of interfaces here are solving a coupling problem that might actually never exist - that's the point I am trying to make. Unless the OP intends on having multiple `Status` or `Control` implementations then what other value do interfaces add here? I am not saying interfaces are a *bad* idea but you could just as easily solve the coupling with events...